# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow, version 14.0.0.0' when opening tfs XAML build on vs 2017

Tags: c#, tfs, build, .net-assembly

When opening TFS XAML build on vs 2017 the error popup shows but its working fine in vs 2015. We cannot seem to find any missing reference for this assembly. thank you.

We've update all the assembly reference to vs 2017 
[error popup image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCXgS.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can find the DLL for 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow in `c:\program files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer`.

Please check if the version matches with the one you have.
If the version matches, clean project, restart your tfs server (to clear cache) and build again.
If the version doesnt match, use the correct version (14.0.0.0) and clean project, restart your tfs server (to clear cache) and build again.

Comment: we've changed all tfs references to your suggestion but when opening our tfs xaml definition this error shows: Error: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a client side environment issue. Have a try with below solution came from this similar question: ["Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build, Version=14.0.0.0" after switching to VS 2017](https://github.com/deadlydog/New-NuGetPackage/issues/1)

> Install the Microsoft Build Tools 2015
>   https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48159

Besides also try to  [clear  TFS cache](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/willy-peter_schaub/2010/09/15/if-you-have-problems-with-tfs-or-visual-studio-flush-the-user-cache-or-not/), which may do the trick.

If all above still not work, please also upgrade your visual studio version to the latest of VS2017.